# Passing data from view controller in Objective C to controller in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to pass a value from a "pictureView" view controller written in objective C to a "profileView" view controller written with swift. I am trying to use the prepare for segue method using the following code

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"unwindToProfileView"]){
    profileView *controller = (profileView *)segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.valueToPass = "PassedValue";
   }
}
```

The problem i'm running into is the "profileView" view controller is not recognized when called from the above method in objective C and xcode is throwing an error. I'm not sure if this is the correct way about transferring data from objective C to swift view controller or if I need to do something in the header or profileView.swift file.

Hopefully this is not a duplicate. I haven't been able to find anything regarding transferring data from objc VC to swift VC. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Add an Objective-C Bridging Header and import the "profileView" view controller in that bridging header. You will then be able to reference the "profileView" view controller.

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: I added the profile view to the bridging header using #import "profileView-Swift.h" but the same errors are showing. I still don't think it is recognizing "profileView" as a view controller. the profileView controller identifier is also named properly.

Comment: You also need to import any frameworks that profileView uses, like UIKit and Foundation. Double check that the Objective-C Bridging Header in the Build Settings (under Swift Compiler - Code Generation) is set to something like `<YourProjectName>/profileView-Swift.h`

Comment: Hmm ya bridging header is correct under build settings and all frameworks are imported into the objective C file. Still not connecting the view controller though.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to my question, I never really got it working the way I wanted. But the way I got around the problem was creating a global variable in Obj C that Swift was able to see. You just have to make sure that global variable is included in your bridging header.